# how to learn detail about all kind of tools about python

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, anaconda

Before python i was using C++ for all kinds of project

Recently, I am trying to install all kinds of tools for python such as Pycharm for compiler pip ,ananconda for packages, pyenv for python version control.

However, i still got some question about how python works. for example why do pycharm need something call interpreter , i know c++ is compiler to asm and through assembler to machine code.
and how does pip and anaconda work isn't they the same tools?

where can i find some lecture or resource teaching about all kinds of issue above?

thanks

Comment: If you fell like if an answer has solved your problem, @Paga, please accept it by clicking on the accept symbol under the votes of the answer, so that future users looking for an answer will know that's the way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is an interpreted language. So you don't have to *explicitly* compile it as the Python interpreter will do that for you. Once you write you code you can compile **and** run it by typing `python file.py` – I'd suggest you to read [this](https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/#:%7E:text=To%20run%20Python%20scripts%20with,python3%20hello.py%20Hello%20World!) to learn more about that (e.g. flags, modules, etc...).

Pip and Conda are two package managers. It means that you can use them to install external python packages into your Python environment. The main difference between the two is that while pip is included in the source you installed when you installed Python, Conda must be installed later.

For example to [install packages using pip](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) you just have to type `pip install <package name>`. For example, to install [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) you would have to write

```sh
pip install numpy
```

I don't use Pycharm as code editor, but I am pretty sure it requires a Python installation to run your scripts directly inside your IDLE (e.g. not from the command line).

However Conda is just one of the tools of Anaconda. The main use of Anaconda is to create Virtual Environments, I'd suggest you to read [this](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) to know more about them.

Comment: thanks for reply. what really confuse me is between using pip for installation like pip install or using conda install will it be a problem for mixing these two.tools why or why not. i know there're bunch of resource i can google but i want to learn about how they really work in system

Comment: I'd suggest you – except in some rare cases – to never mix pip and conda. Because external packages are installed in a folder in your system, that is differs which package manager you are using. To know how do they work you can just read [the documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/), that explains it better that I can do with a Stack Overflow post. @Paga